# How do I import XML files into Plone so that each field value is stored in its corresponding AT field?

Tags: xml, import, plone, archetypes

I am trying to import XML files into Plone. The methods described in the tutorial on "http://plone.org/documentation/kb/xml-in-plone-with-marshall/tutorial-all-pages" work fine for viewing a Plone Page in XML; however, importing an XML always inserts the entire file contents as HTML-encoded characters into the <field name="text"> tag.

I have a page called "my-test-page.atxmlpage" with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<metadata xmlns="http://plone.org/ns/archetypes/" xmlns:cmf="http://cmf.zope.org/namespaces/default/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xmp="adobe:ns:meta">
<dc:title>
    My Test Page
</dc:title>
<dc:creator>
    admin
</dc:creator>
<dc:language>
    en
</dc:language>
<xmp:CreateDate>
    2011-09-06T19:00:27Z
</xmp:CreateDate>
<xmp:ModifyDate>
    2011-09-06T19:01:01Z
</xmp:ModifyDate>
<field name="id">
    my-test-page
</field>
<field name="text">
    Hello world!
</field>

<cmf:type>
    Document
</cmf:type>
<cmf:workflow_history>
    <cmf:workflow id="simple_publication_workflow">
        <cmf:history>
            <cmf:var id="action" type="None" value="None"/>
            <cmf:var id="actor" type="str" value="admin"/>
            <cmf:var id="comments" type="str" value=""/>
            <cmf:var id="review_state" type="str" value="private"/>
            <cmf:var id="time" type="date" value="2011-09-06 15:00:27"/>
        </cmf:history>
    </cmf:workflow>
</cmf:workflow_history>
<cmf:security>
    <cmf:local_role role="Owner" user_id="admin"/>
</cmf:security>
</metadata>
```

When I try to import this file into Plone (either via FTP over 8021 or WEBDAV over the source port 9880), the page loads with all of the content (starting with the  tag) into the  field. The correct thing to do would be for Plone to load each field value into its correct AT field. The  field should only contain the text "Hello world!".

How do I teach Plone to correctly import an XML file?

NOTES:

My /Plone/marshaller_register/ contains two Predicate Constraints: an ATXMLMarshaller with this condition: python: mode=='marshall' and an ATXMLMarshaller with this condition: python: mode='demarshall' and content_type=='text/xml'.

My /Plone/content_type_registry/ contains a Page predicate for the .atxmlpage extension (as per the instructions in the above-mentioned tutorial).

Plone version 3.3.4.
Marshall version 1.2.1.
Python version 2.4.4.